# How to select all rows if no conditions are met within a group and select a subset of rows if certain conditions within a group are met in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In the dataframe below:

```
pd.DataFrame({'customer': ['cust1', 'cust1', 'cust1', 'cust2', 'cust2', 'cust3', 'cust3', 'cust4', 'cust4'],
                   'year': [2017, 2018, 2019, 2018, 2019, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2019],
                   'score': [0.10, 0.59, 0.3, 0.44, 0.2, 0.78, 0.6, 0.37, .023]})

    customer    year    score
0   cust1   2017    0.100
1   cust1   2018    0.590
2   cust1   2019    0.300
3   cust2   2018    0.440
4   cust2   2019    0.200
5   cust3   2017    0.780
6   cust3   2018    0.600
7   cust4   2018    0.370
8   cust4   2019    0.023
```

I want to filter the data within each group of customers. the conditions are:

```
if the score >= 0.5: return only rows greater than 0.5 in that group
if no score is greater than 0.5 in a group: return all the rows
```

The result should look like this:

```
    customer    year    cond
0   cust1   2018    0.590
1   cust2   2018    0.440
2   cust2   2019    0.200
3   cust3   2017    0.780
4   cust3   2018    0.600
5   cust4   2018    0.370
6   cust4   2019    0.023
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chain 2 conditions - first mask is for test if greater or equal by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) and for second get all `customer` if no match condition `m`:

```
m = df['score'].ge(0.5)
df = df[m | ~df['customer'].isin(df.loc[m, 'customer'])]
print (df)
  customer  year  score
1    cust1  2018  0.590
3    cust2  2018  0.440
4    cust2  2019  0.200
5    cust3  2017  0.780
6    cust3  2018  0.600
7    cust4  2018  0.370
8    cust4  2019  0.023
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.loc[m, 'customer'])
1    cust1
5    cust3
6    cust3
Name: customer, dtype: object

print (~df['customer'].isin(df.loc[m, 'customer']))
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7     True
8     True
Name: customer, dtype: bool
```

Or if performance is no important use for second mask [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) - should be slow in large DataFrames:

```
m = df['score'].ge(0.5)
df = df[m | ~m.groupby(df['customer']).transform('any')]
print (df)
  customer  year  score
1    cust1  2018  0.590
3    cust2  2018  0.440
4    cust2  2019  0.200
5    cust3  2017  0.780
6    cust3  2018  0.600
7    cust4  2018  0.370
8    cust4  2019  0.023
```

**Details**:

```
print (~m.groupby(df['customer']).transform('any'))
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7     True
8     True
Name: score, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use two masks for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# is the score ≥ 0.5?
m1 = df['score'].ge(0.5)
# are none of values in the group ≥ 0.5
m2 = ~m1.groupby(df['customer']).transform('any')

# select if any condition matches
out = df[m1|m2]
```

Output:

```
  customer  year  score
1    cust1  2018  0.590
3    cust2  2018  0.440
4    cust2  2019  0.200
5    cust3  2017  0.780
6    cust3  2018  0.600
7    cust4  2018  0.370
8    cust4  2019  0.023
```